# Wrong type detection in lodash/sortBy with TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, lodash

It seems that `lodash/sortBy` detects the type of 2nd argument of iteratee function (comparator) incorrectly. It relates to both named and default lodash imports.
At the same time, `stable` sorting helper detects it properly.

(sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-haslett-be2h6)

Question: May I doing smth wrong or there is a problem with _.sortBy with TS?

```js
import _ from "lodash";
import sortBy from "lodash/sortBy";
import stable from "stable";

export interface ITableRow {
  accountId: number;
  companyName: string;
}

const rows: ITableRow[] = [];

// TS error
const sortedList1 = sortBy<ITableRow>(
  rows,
  (a, b) => a.accountId - b.accountId
);

// TS error
const sortedList2 = _.sortBy<ITableRow>(
  rows,
  (a, b) => a.accountId - b.accountId
);

// ok
const sortedList3 = stable<ITableRow>(
  rows,
  (a, b) => a.accountId - b.accountId
);
```

Comment: But `sortBy` does not take a comparator like what you'd use in a JS `.sort`. It takes an iteratee which expects a single argument. What you want to do can even be done by either passing `x => x.accountId` or the shorthand `"accountId"` (the string).

Comment: @VLAZ thanks a lot, you're right!